# Local : Global :: Localite :?

Tags: meaning, is-it-a-word, analogy

**Context:**
I want to indicate people who keep travelling around the world (sometimes as part of their jobs and sometimes to volunteer during a crisis) without settling down at a single country.

I came across terms like [Global Citizens / World Citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_citizenship), but I want to know if I can use *Globalite*, albeit as a neologism, such that it will be analogous with *Localite*

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/localite) does define *localite*, but not *globalite*

localite (noun)

> a native or resident of the locality under consideration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think as a single word  [***cosmopolite***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cosmopolite) may convey the idea:

> - a person familiar with and at ease in many different countries and cultures.

In this [extract](https://books.google.it/books?id=9U1K5LjUOwEC&pg=PA207&dq=%22localite%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji84Sc9-TJAhUHtRQKHVogDKkQ6AEILDAC#v=onepage&q=%22localite%22&f=false), for instance, it is used as an antonym of localite:

> - Cosmopolite channels are relatively more important at the knowledge stage, and localite channels are relatively more important at the persuasion stage in the innovation- decision ...

and also [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=sbVnvEcFjf0C&pg=PA86&dq=%22localite%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYmdHM-OTJAhUEPBQKHbQKAqk4ChDoAQgnMAI#v=onepage&q=%22localite%22&f=false):

> - Information Seeking Behaviour of Livestock Farmers Sources of Information It is evident from Table 6.9, that majority of the respondents belonged to medium category in acquiring information from personal-localite, personal-cosmopolite and ...

The term "localite", though present in dictionaries, in not a common one, and I'd avoid using "globalite". World/global citizen are good options.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of **cosmopolitan**. Not sure how I missed this...