# can we use `localite` for business entity?

Tags: word-usage

if any business was started in particular area, can we use "localite" for that business entity?

> For example: *This business is localite to this area*.

Comment: Where did you get *localite* from? What does your own research in a dictionary say?

Comment: And what does "in particular are then can" mean?

Comment: Do you mean "*localized in this area*"? A "localized business" is one that chooses to market its products or services through a physical location (or locations) situated in a reasonable proximity to its customers. Howevr, you may say that "*the company is localized inside of Venice Commercial Port and perfectly connected to main terminals portual*.

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294702/local-global-localite

Answer (score 2):

"Localite" is not in the Oxford English Dictionary.

However, a search in GloWbE (the global corpus of web-based English) gives nine hits for it: eight in Indian sources, and one from Singapore.

So it would appear that it is a word which has limited currency in India, and apparently in Singapore, but is unknown elsewhere in the Anglosphere. (I observe that all but one of the nine instances used it as a noun, clearly meaning "a local person". One of them is an adjective used attributively. I have not found a single instance of "is localite".

Answer (score 1):

Just use "local". I also wouldn't use the word "this" twice.

> *This business is **local** to the area.*